# Update table based on column from deleted row

Tags: sql

I need to delete a row from `users_vip` if the current timestamp is greater than the timestamp in the `expires` column.

After that, I need to update my `users` table and set `rank` to `1` for the `user_id` that got deleted from `users_vip`.

```
CREATE TABLE `users_vip` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11),
    `expires` TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `rank` INT(11)
);
```

I do this with events by running a delete query every hour, but I have no come any further.

```
DELETE FROM users_vip WHERE NOW() > expires
```

If I can demonstrate what I mean:

```
DELETE FROM users_vip WHERE NOW() > expires
UPDATE users SET rank = "4" WHERE user_id = users_vip.user_id
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Reverse the order of steps. First update `users`  to be deleted, then delete from  `users_vip`

Comment: @Serg Understood. But I have to then delete from `users_vip` the users I changed the ranks from 4 to 1, if that makes sense? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first update users to be deleted, then delete

```
UPDATE users 
  SET rank = '4'
  WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users_vip WHERE NOW() > expires)

DELETE FROM users_vip WHERE NOW() > expires
```